# Klazuka/Kal incorporation issue

Tags: ios

I'm having a little issue.  I am trying to incorporate the Klazuka/Kal project into my project.  I've done the following:

1. I added the Kal.xcodeproj and all files to my project
2. Under Build Phases, I've added Kal to "Target Dependencies"
3. Under Build Phases, I've added libKal.a under "Link Binary With Libraries"
4. Under Build Phases, I've added Kal.bundle to "Copy Bundle Resources"
5. Under Build Settings, I've added "“$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)” (or “$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/static_library_name”" for "Header Search Paths" and "User Header Search Paths".
6. Under Build Settings, I've added the path to Kal under "Library Search Paths"
7. Under Build Settings, I've added -ObjC, -all_load, and -force_load under "Other Linker Flags"
8. I've edited my Build Scheme and list the Kal Target prior to my main application target with Analyze, Test, Run, Profile, and Archive all checked.

I've attempted to follow the steps from here on Stack Overflow: [iphone: Kal calendar not running in xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321285/iphone-kal-calendar-not-running-in-xcode-4-2)

and here:  [Trying to integrate a Calendar library that was built for versions of iOS before iOS5 into my new project in XCode 4 using iOS5 - How to port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746303/trying-to-integrate-a-calendar-library-that-was-built-for-versions-of-ios-before/8746395#8746395)

and here:  [I added my project and Kal Calendar's project in a workspace, still won't work in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223682/i-added-my-project-and-kal-calendars-project-in-a-workspace-still-wont-work-i)

and also on this site: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/#configuring_the_projects_scheme

I try to import the "Kal.h" file but am getting a File Not Found error when I try to build. I'm obviously missing something, just not sure what.  Can anyone please help?  Thanks for any assistance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind...Apparently there was a problem with my step 5.  I changed User Header Search Paths to the actual path of the Klazuka files and it builds fine.